# Why does the net torque not turn this object?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, friction, torque

Here the object does not spin on the surface. (point $O$ has $M_o = 0$) However, there are non-zero net torques on the object at points $A$ and $B$ ($M_a$, $M_b \neq 0$). Why do these net torques not cause the object to start turning?

My opinion is that the normal force is constantly displacing each instant of time. Rotations are prevented in these displacements.

[image]

Comment: Why do you have a single normal force vector? Why don't you have a distribution of normal forces across the whole surface? You can't model a contact surface with a single force if you're calculating torques.

Comment: How was the point _O_ decided? In general, the line of action of the reaction is such that not tipping happens.

Comment: @ ja72 To prevent the object from falling, If at any other point, the Object falls

Comment: @ Bill N There is only one normal force, this is the location of the total normal force..

Comment: One could consider a *bump* present at the location of point $O$ on the surface of the object in the figure to cause this force distribution. In that case the resulting torques would cause the object to start to turn.

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz, a small technical note. I don't think adding a space between `@` and the username (like `@ user`) will cause others to receive pings. Just plainly type `@user` without spaces in between `@` and `user`.

Comment: @Guru Vihnu I'm sorry I did not know

Comment: There are a lot of confusing things here. Presumable, $F_S$ is the static friction force. If it is, it should be 60N not 10N since the only horizontal force opposed by static friction is the applied 60N force and assuming the maximum static friction force is not exceeded. Then what is 40N? The weight of the block? Then there would be an equal and opposite normal reaction force by the surface. Regarding rotation, the only tipping that can occur would be at the lower left corner of the block. That's where the sum of the moments should be taken not point O on your diagram. Clarify these points

Comment: @Bob D the object moves with a net force of 30N. (F-Fs = 30N) Fs = 10N, G = 40 N = 40

Comment: The problem statement makes no mention of the block moving horizontal to the surface. I am voting to close this because it is not providing all the information needed.

Comment: In the drawing where the block moves, it is shown in blue in the direction of movement. Every fade is clear.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is not tipping moment and the block remains level, it means that the normal force *and* friction combined must pass through the center of mass

[image: fig]

With point *O* such that $\tan \theta = \frac{10}{40}$.

Using similar triangles from geometry you can find the location of *O* relative to *A*.

Comment: How does the friction force pass through the center of mass?

Comment: @ja72 So will my object fall over in my drawing?

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz the friction force DOES NOT act through the center of mass (point A). It acts horizontal to the surface.

Comment: @Bob D I know that. Here, the force passing through the center of mass is the combined force...

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz That's not what you said. You said to ja72 "the friction force, not the normal and friction force, passes through the center of mass". That's what you said. The applied force acts through the center of mass. The weight and normal reaction force acts through the center of mass. The friction force does not. It provides a moment about the center of mass. Any way, I have not more time to devote to this.

Comment: @BobD - friction _and_ normal force combined pass through the center of mass. Look at the diagram. The dashed line is the direction of the combine forces through _O_. The dashed line _must_ pass through _A_, otherwise, the forces acting from the ground would create an overturning moment.

Comment: @ja72 To me it's different to talk about the vector combination of the 10N and 40N forces going through A then it is to say the friction force itself passes through the center of mass which is what the OP said to you, and I  quote  "the friction force, not the normal and friction force and friction, passes through A". That is what made no sense to me at all.

Comment: @ja72 Can you answer my question, will the object I draw knock over? Bob, I made a typo, I wanted to say that. my English is not good..

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz - you can't answer that until the location of _O_ is known. What I mean is that either you assume it isn't tipping and you find were _O_ must be (like my answer above) or you know where _O_ is and find if it is tipping (like your question). So where is _O_ located in your diagram (along the bottom of the block).

Comment: @ja72 The location of the point (O) is where the Torque is zero on the ground of the block. where Fs friction force is 20N, torque will be zero at all points.

Comment: @ja72 However, the Fs kinetic friction force is a maximum of 10N. In this case, the Normal force must be at the O point. Because torque relative to the ground is only zero at point O

Comment: @BilgehanYılmaz - honestly I don't understand your comments. The point _O_ is where the normal force is applied, as friction can be _anywhere_ along the bottom.